# Looking for a book series featuring reincarnation across alternate worlds.and timelines

Tags: story-identification

I read this book series over ten years ago.  Certain people get picked up from different worlds and different times, some are different species, still human-ish though. All are "immortal"... there's spaceships, time travel, alternate worlds and universes, reincarnation and also living those reincarnated lives/alternate lives at the same time (if that makes sense).

Love is a big theme too, these certain people are destined for others in this group, through every life, even if they don't realise it yet. There was a psychological spiritual theme to the whole thing.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: My first thought was Eternal Champion (Michael Moorcock)

Comment: What do you mean by "picked up"--what happens to them? Do you remember any characters or scenes, or more specifics about the spaceships/time travel/alternate worlds and etc?